# markov chains communication classes

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In Bremaud's book about markov chains is stated:

> If A is stochastic but not irreducible, then the algebraic and
>   geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalue 1 are equal to the number
>   of communication classes.

But I think that's not true.

Consider two states $\{1,2\}$ with transition matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. P is stochastic and not irreducible. There are $2$ communication classes $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.

But $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $P$, so algebraic multplicity of eigenvalue 1 =$1\ne2$=number of communication classes.

Did I missunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1. I wrote too fast. There are two communication classes: $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.

cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility

Indeed, by definition, each state communicates with itself and moreover, the classes constitute a partition of the set of states. The states $1$ and $2$ do not communicate because $1$ is not accessible from $2$. Finally $\{2\}$ is a closed class and $\{1\}$ is not.

About your second example (cf. your first comment), one has exactly the same result.

EDIT 2. I do many mistakes. I think that your second comment is true. I have only that follows:

One has the following .

Proposition. If $A$ admits $r$ closed classes, then its eigenvalue $1$ has  a multiplicity $\geq r$.

Proof. Assume that $\{1,\cdots,k\}$ is a closed class (no out-arrows). Then $A$ is of the form: $\begin{pmatrix}B&0\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$ where $B$ is stochastic and irreducible. Then the eigenvalue $\rho(B)=1$ is simple and is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: I read the article but I think you're wrong. But if we choose $P=\begin{pmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ state $1$ and $2$ communicate with theirselves but $1$ and $2$ don't communicate with each other. So there are two communication classes $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, but 1 is here a simple eigenvalue again.

Comment: I think the statement is right only for closed communication classes.